# Second order Non-homogeneous differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

When solving an equation in the form 
$$
ay''+by'= cx^2+dx+f
$$
I find that it has a complementary equation with a constant, and so I have difficulties when I attempt to find the particular integral.

Usually the particular integral would be of the form $y=Kx^2+Lx+M$: 
however since the complementary equation has a constant my maths book tells me to use $y= Kx^3+Lx^2+Mx$ and I don't understand why.
Why does a complementary equation with a constant term influence the form of the particular integral?

Comment: The true  reason is that the l.h.s. has no term in $y$, and when differentiating polynomials, the degree is $1$ less.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. Please consider using [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the mathematical text of your questions: it helps you to type beautiful mathematics and helps other members help you.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda=0$ is solution of characteristic equation $a\lambda^2+b\lambda=0$ order
$s=1$,

$cx^2+dx+f$ is polynomial degree $2$. Then
$$y_p=x^s(Kx^2+Lx+N)=x(Kx^2+Lx+N).$$

You can get
$$y_p=x\, \left( \frac{c\, {{x}^{2}}}{3 b}+\frac{\left( b d-2 a c\right)  x}{2 {{b}^{2}}}+\frac{{{b}^{2}} f-a b d+2 {{a}^{2}} c}{{{b}^{3}}}\right) $$